# Print ESCPOS Image c#

Tags: c#, image, escpos

So, i'm building a program to print in escpos printers by a command sent by a service.
I managed everything, the text, align, font size etc. Now I need to print an image that is sent in octet-stream
How do i do that? i've tried everything

the image string is ////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4P/////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4P/////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4P/////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4P/////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4P/////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAH8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAH///B//wAH8AAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAA//4AAD///B//wAH8AAAAAGAAAAD/4AA///gA//4AAD///B//wAH8AAAAAHAAAAP/+AA///gA//4AAD///B//wAH8AAAAAPAAAAf//AA///gA//4AAD///B//wAH8AAAAAPgAAA///gA///gA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAAfgAAB/g/AAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAAfwAAD+AOAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAA/wAAD8AAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH//+AAA/4AAH4AAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH//+AAB/4AAHwAAAAAfAAA//4AP////B//wAH//+AAB98AAPwAAAAAfAAA//4AH////B//wAH//+AAD58AAPwAAAAAfAAA//4AH////B//wAH//+AAD5+AAPwAAAAAfAAA//4AH////B//wAH8AAAAHw+AAPgAAAAAfAAA//4AH////B//wAH8AAAAHw/AAPwAAAAAfAAA//4AP////B//wAH8AAAAPgfAAPwAAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAPgfAAPwAAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAf//gAH4AAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAf//gAH4AAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAA///wAH8AAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAA///wAD+AOAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAB///4AB/w/AAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAB8AD4AA///gAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAD8AB8AAf//AAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAD4AB8AAP/+AAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH4AAAD4AA+AAD/4AAAfAAA/////////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

```
I was trying this
 oby = new List<byte>();
            oby.Add(Convert.ToByte(0x1B));
            oby.Add(Convert.ToByte(0x2A));
            oby.Add(Convert.ToByte(33));
            Bytes = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(Bytes, oby.ToArray());
            Bytes = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(Bytes, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4P/////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4P/////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4P/////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4P/////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4P/////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAH8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAH///B//wAH8AAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAA//4AAD///B//wAH8AAAAAGAAAAD/4AA///gA//4AAD///B//wAH8AAAAAHAAAAP/+AA///gA//4AAD///B//wAH8AAAAAPAAAAf//AA///gA//4AAD///B//wAH8AAAAAPgAAA///gA///gA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAAfgAAB/g/AAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAAfwAAD+AOAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAA/wAAD8AAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH//+AAA/4AAH4AAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH//+AAB/4AAHwAAAAAfAAA//4AP////B//wAH//+AAB98AAPwAAAAAfAAA//4AH////B//wAH//+AAD58AAPwAAAAAfAAA//4AH////B//wAH//+AAD5+AAPwAAAAAfAAA//4AH////B//wAH8AAAAHw+AAPgAAAAAfAAA//4AH////B//wAH8AAAAHw/AAPwAAAAAfAAA//4AP////B//wAH8AAAAPgfAAPwAAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAPgfAAPwAAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAf//gAH4AAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAAf//gAH4AAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAA///wAH8AAAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAA///wAD+AOAAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAB///4AB/w/AAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAB8AD4AA///gAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAD8AB8AAf//AAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH8AAAD4AB8AAP/+AAAfAAA//4P/////B//wAH4AAAD4AA+AAD/4AAAfAAA/////////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////////B//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//4AAAAAAB//wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"));
```

doesn't work :D
i tried a lot more, but I don't think it would fit in this textarea :D

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the width of the bit image in 2 bytes between `oby.Add (Convert.ToByte (33));` and the image data.

Please refer to the following.
The corresponding page is in Japanese.
[ESC *](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos_ja/index.php?content_id=88)

ESC * m nL nH d1 ... dk

For example, assuming that the variable ImageWidth contains the width value, it becomes as follows.

```
oby.Add(Convert.ToByte(0x1B));
oby.Add(Convert.ToByte(0x2A));
oby.Add(Convert.ToByte(33));
oby.Add(Convert.ToByte(ImageWidth & 0xFF));
oby.Add(Convert.ToByte((ImageWidth & 0xFF00)>>8));
Bytes = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(Bytes, oby.ToArray());
```

Comment: And when do you had the image string? Let's imagine that the image is 80x80px and the string of image is /////aaaaa//////bbbb////test//////123

Comment: Image data(960 bytes) may be added following the above as you wrote. The size calculation(960) is ((24bit / 8bit) * ((80 + 23) / 24))(=vertical) * 80(=horizontal).